# Issue Using Flex SDK in Flash Professional (for as3corelib)

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I recently found Mike Chambers' as3corelib when looking for ways to render the stage to a file. Works great in my ActionScript 3.0 project in Flash Professional (CS6 if it matters).

I decided to look at some of Mike's utility classes, notably the date related ones. However, his DateUtil class imports mx.formatters.DateBase, and when I attempt to use some of the methods, I'm getting lots (and lots) of "Access of undefined property DateBase."

I'm assuming that's because some reference to the Flex SDK is missing or wrong. I've added $(FlexSDK)/frameworks/libs/flex.swc to my project's Library path, but that's not helping.

I've used Flash for years, but this is my first truly code-centric project, and still learning through the school of hard knocks. No idea what's going wrong here. Ideas?

---

Example from as3corelib

```
package com.adobe.utils
{
    import mx.formatters.DateBase;

    /**
    *   Class that contains static utility methods for manipulating and working
    *   with Dates.
    */  
    public class DateUtil
    {

        /**
        * Returns a date string formatted according to RFC822.
        */  
        public static function toRFC822(d:Date):String
        {
            var date:Number = d.getUTCDate();
            var hours:Number = d.getUTCHours();
            var minutes:Number = d.getUTCMinutes();
            var seconds:Number = d.getUTCSeconds();
            var sb:String = new String();
            sb += DateBase.dayNamesShort[d.getUTCDay()];
            sb += ", ";

...
```

The line:

```
sb += DateBase.dayNamesShort[d.getUTCDay()];
```

...generates the mentioned error, as does any other DateBase reference in the class. Again, this code is directly from the latest as3corelib, located on GitHub:  https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib

Comment: Using UI Flex classes in Flash Pro is going to be problematic.  I would not expect DateBase to have any UI dependencies, but without reviewing code it is hard to say.  You'll have to share some of the lines of code that are causing errors for us to help or point you in a direction.

Comment: Reboog, the errors are not in my code, they occur in Chambers' as3corelib (https://github.com/mikechambers/as3corelib), which is sort of represented as being a general-purpose library for ActionScript 3.0. In his DateUtil class, he imports mx.formatters.DateBase. But then any reference to DateBase across his static methods throws the "Access of undefined property DateBase" error. I was hoping someone here was familiar with this library, since it seems to be widely used, and would know what I'm missing.

Comment: Are you unable to "share some of the lines of code that are causing errors"?  Do you not have the source code?  If the import is the only problem, then did you add the Flex SWCs to the library path of your project?

Comment: Refer back to the original post; the Flex SWC is referenced in the path, yes. Editing the original to include an example.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether you got this one licked or not, but I hit the same thing.  Love the library, hate the error messages.

I downloaded the Flex SDK from here:

[Adobe Flex SDK Download](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/flex-sdk-download.html)

Then, I unzipped that into a temporary folder.

Then, since I didn't want the whole flex framework lurking about, I created a ./lib directory inside the directory where the .fla file lives.  I then moved these swcs from here (Inside the unzipped file structure):

```
mv ~/Downloads/flex_sdk_4.6/frameworks/libs/framework.swc ./lib
mv ~/Downloads/flex_sdk_4.6/frameworks/libs/core.swc ./lib
mv ~/Downloads/flex_sdk_4.6/frameworks/libs/mx/mx.swc ./lib
```

Not sure why all three were required, but it stopped the compiler complaining (and got the date conversions working).

You need to add them to the .fla's library list as well (under ActionScript Settings); but I'm betting you already knew that.

Perhaps useful, perhaps not.