# Google IMA flash SDK issues

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-ima

Would someone please help me run the sample files? I cannot understand Google Guide (no experience with ActionScript as I am a Java developer) but want to run some vpaid tags using this SDK.

I have installed Adobe Flash CC 2014. Also have integrated ima_lib_as3.swc into flash (available in Components). Now I created a new ActionScript 3.0 (flv) file and in actions included this.

```
var t:SdkIntegrationExample=new SdkIntegrationExample();
```

When I try to compile I get the following error

```
/Users/xxx/Documents/Test.as, Line 77, Column 60    1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: VideoPlayer.
/Users/xxx/Documents/Test.as, Line 358, Column 47   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: FlexEvent.
/Users/xxx/Documents/Test.as, Line 380, Column 61   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: TimeEvent.
/Users/xxx/Documents/Test.as, Line 398, Column 61   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: FlexEvent.
/Users/xxx/Documents/Test.as, Line 410, Column 51   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: TimeEvent.
```

Would someone guide me in the right direction, and break down the procedure in easy terminology?

Comment: You didn't ask a real question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17027429/issue-using-flex-sdk-in-flash-professional-for-as3corelib

Comment: [This search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Type+was+not+found+or+was+not+a+compile-time+constant) seems relevant.